# Node Group missing from sidebar

Tags: node-editor

I'm fairly new to blender and was following a tutorial for procedural textures and it involved making a node group and then changing the group input type to a float. My sidebar in the node editor doesn't seem to have a group tab, and no apparent way to change the input settings and I was wondering if there is something I am missing. I've attached a picture of my node workspace. If anyone can help me understand the issue I'd greatly appreciate it!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you indicate which version of Blender you are using, and also share your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com ?

Comment: "normally" if you select the group input node, you should have a "group" tab on the right side...

Comment: I'm using 2.82 I believe I've attached the file above as well thanks. Yes, I'm still not sure why there is no group tab showing up on the sidebar

Comment: Would be interesting to know which version you are using. I've opened the file with 3.6.5, 4.0.1 and 4.0.2 and all versions show the _Group_ tab in the sidebar. Only difference I saw in 3.6.5: the tab was on fourth position, while usually it's on top. From the top of my head I don't know a setting which would turn that off, so probably if it is not a matter of the version and the setting you might need to re-install Blender? Report a bug?

Comment: Thanks! I updated to a newer version and its working fine now, must have been an issue with the version I was using